# How To Remove Mailbox for Deleted AD Account

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I have some 'orphaned' mailboxes in Exchange 2010 with the AD account deleted. If I try to mark them for removal using the GUI I get:

'The object could not be performed because object X could not be found'.

Where X is the AD object.

What's the best way around this? Is there a powershell solution?

Answer (score 3):

From PowerShell:

> Get-DisconnectedMailbox

If you have many mailbox servers you could run something like this to get an org wide list:

> Get-ExchangeServer | Where-Object {$*.IsMailboxServer -eq $true} | Get-MailboxStatistics | where-object {$*.DisconnectDate -NotLike ''} | FT DisplayName,DatabaseName,TotalItemSize

and then to get rid of them:

> Remove-StoreMailbox -Database $DatabaseName -Identity $MailboxID
>   -MailboxState SoftDeleted

Where the $DatabaseName is the source database and the $MailboxID is the full StoreMailboxID name.

Resource: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg181092%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx